# Mercurial Bitbucket jenkins plugin 500 error

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure bitbucket (Mercurial) and Jenkins.
I installed the Bitbucket Jenkins plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin

on Bitbucket, I configure a new webhook:
http://X.X.X.X:8080/jenkins/bitbucket-hook/
and I can see that a called is done everytime I pushed my commits:
Event: repo:push
Details: 2 minutes ago
**Error: 500**

On Jenkins Logs I can see that a JSON is received:

Received commit hook notification for

```
 {
  "scm": "hg",
  "uuid": "{6c2bcf03-9371-4a6b-bef4-XXXXXXXX}",
  "is_private": true,
  "full_name": "XXXXXXX/XXXXXXdy09",
  "name": "XXXX-dy09",
  "type": "repository",
  "links": {
    "html": {
      "href": "https://bitbucket.org/XXXXXXX/YYYYYYs-dy09"
    },
    "avatar": {
      "href": "https://bitbucket.org/XXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYdy09/avatar/32/"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/XXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYYYdy09"
    }
  },
  "owner": {
    "display_name": "XXXXXXX",
    "uuid": "{bca96c46-239a-4dd7-885e-XXXXXXX}",
    "links": {
      "html": {
        "href": "https://bitbucket.org/XXXXXXXXXXX/"
      },
      "avatar": {
        "href": "https://bitbucket.org/account/XXXXXXXXXX/avatar/32/"
      },
      "self": {
        "href": "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/XXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    },
    "username": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "type": "user"
  }
}
```

but nothing is happening, any job is triggered.

Jenkins Job conf:
[image]

Any idea why my job is not triggered?

Thx in advance

Comment: Bitbucket has been having issues with the website lately. See [status.bitbucket.org](http://status.bitbucket.org/)

Comment: I know, I was checking its twitter account: https://twitter.com/bitbucketstatus 
but it wasn't because of it. feel free to have a look to my own answer.

Comment: You can use this plugin to trigger the job:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/

Resolve whatever values you need from the json and then use command line to fetch your repo.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I'm going to ask my own asnwer.

it seems Mercurial is not supported at this moment.
in the following link:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/BitbucketJobProbe.java

you could see:

```
 if ("git".equals(scm)) {

//more code
 } else {
            // TODO hg
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported SCM type " + scm);
 }
```

so, not possible using the bitbucket plugin. 
there are many workarounds you can find on internet.